# How do I enable a slow query log for Amazon "Aurora MySQL" engine?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

There seems to be no information on AWS "Aurora MySQL" about how to pull out slow query logs.  I am not using RDS / MySQL - I am using Aurora.

Answer (score 4):

Go Into AWS > RDS > Parameter Groups > { select the parameter group you you db is in } > Click Edit Parameters > find slow query log and set to 1.

[image]

Comment: That is cool - how to I see the contents of the slow query log?

Comment: Go to Cloudwatch, then find log groups on the left.

Answer (score 1):

In the "mysql" database, open the "slow_log" table and you can view the slow queries.

Comment: the question was on RDS so opening the log file is not an option unless i missed something.

Comment: It is a table called slow_log inside the mysql database.

Comment: ok make sense then. You might consider editing the answer for make that clearer since i didn't get it correctly at the 1st look. cheers

Comment: yes there is no change of confusion then. thank you for that.